# Parallels Plesk: Add domain alias to a sub domain

Tags: apache-http-server, parallels

I would like to add a domain alias to a sub domain in parallels plesk 11.5.
I am able to do it from /var/www/vhost/sites.adomain.com/conf/vhost.conf

But i want to do this from parallels panel.

Please help.